# Problem involving limit and sum

Tags: limits, summation

Let $a_n$ be a sequence satisfying $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(na_n-\frac{n^2+1}{2n+1} \right)=3$$

Compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n^2+2a_n+2)$.

I have tried  $(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n))^2+2\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n)+2$
using several limit properities, but what can I do further?

Comment: Hint: note that for a series to converge, the sequence of $n$-th terms (not partial sums) must converge to $0$.

Answer (score 4):

If the first series is convergent its general term converges to zero, hence $a_n\to \frac{1}{2}$ and $(a_n+1)^2+1\to \frac{13}{4}$.

Comment: How you came up with the values. Can you be more specific I rely want to understand your approach? Thanks in advance

Comment: What a clever solution! (+1)

Comment: @hypergeometric if you can understand how to come up with this  solution please help me to understand it.

Comment: @YulduzRahmatova: if $na_n-\frac{n^2+1}{2n+1}\to 0$, then $a_n\to\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio this is very interesting how you found that  $na_n−\frac{n2+1}{2n+1}\rightarrow 0$. Can you add that in your answer or in the feedback please.

Comment: @R.Temur: if $\sum_{n\geq 1}b_n$ is convergent then $b_n\to 0$. That's written in the first line of my answer.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio yes now everything is clear for me

Comment: Jack has already answered quite clearly in his comment to you and to R.Temur. Basically, as $n\to \infty$,  each term $\left(na_n-\frac {n^2+1}{2n+1}\right)\to 0$ , i.e. $na_n\to \frac {n^2+1}{2n+1}$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {n^2+1}{2n+1}=\frac {n^2}{2n}=\frac n2$, which gives $a_n\to\frac 12$. Hopefully this is correct.